# Any other reputation bonus, except association?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

In our [reputation audit page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation), there is such line near the end:

> ** rep from bonuses: `___`

Does the use of plural word mean there are other bonuses except association, maybe secret?

Has anyone ever saw a number other 0 or 100 in there?

Comment: Never seen any other bonuses. My guess would be that wording was a just in case thing... hmm...

Comment: @AndrewBarber my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: is this perhaps the 100 rep you get if you join a new site after having rep on another SO site (eg you start from 101 rep)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor yes, I'm well aware of the association bonus, looking for other bonuses.

Comment: Yes, there is a secret bonus. You get 42 bonus points for answering this question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/the-meaning-of-life

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, testers and contributors to the first version of the API received badges that also had bonuses.  This is exclusive to [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/).  For example, [see the 2k bonus here](https://stackapps.com/users/12/adam-davis?tab=reputation).

The badges involved were the [API Beta](https://stackapps.com/help/badges/59/api-beta) and [API Evangelist](https://stackapps.com/help/badges/60/api-evangelist).  These were awarded manually.

And yes, I agree, the "rep change" description in the reputation tab sucks.  It sucks because it's really old, hasn't been used since, and we have no plans to use it again.

Comment: Thanks, so no plans to set new kind of bonus in the near future, or implement badges that give reputation elsewhere? :-)